# Use a function in a v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, v-for

I am trying to create a menu on Vue 3 with categories and subcategories. The goal is that when I click on a category, the subcategories specific to that category will appear below and be removed when I click again. The problem is that I can't get the function to be specific to each category. Whenever I click on a category, the subcategories of all categories are displayed.

I reproduced my code in a simpler example.

JS :

```
const menu = [
  {
    label: "Category 1",
    key: "category_1",
    subcategories: [
      {
        label: "1 - Subcategory 1",
        key: "1_subcategory_1",
      },
      {
        label: "1 - Subcategory 2",
        key: "1_subcategory_2",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: "Category 2",
    key: "category_2",
    children: [
      {
        label: "2 - Subcategory 1",
        key: "2_subcategory_1",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const isDisplay = ref(false);

const showSubcategories = () => {
  isDisplay.value = !isDisplay.value
}
```

VUE :

```
<template>
  <div v-for="category in menu" :key="category.key">
    <div @click="showSubcategories()">
      <span> {{ category.label }}</span>
    </div>
    <div v-if="isDisplay">
      <div
        v-for="subcategory in category.subcategories"
        :key="subcategory.key"
      >
        {{ subcategory.label }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I suspect that I have to add an index (like `showSubcategories(category.key)`)or pass one or more parameters to my function but despite my attempts, I can't solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there are multiple menus that can be opened simultaneously then you need to store all their ids. Otherwise you need to store a specific id. It's not enough to have isDisplay  boolean state. "I suspect that I have to add an index" - yes,  you do. "but despite my attempts" - they aren't shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options to do this. You can add additional property to each category to track if it is open or not, or you can have a separate variable to store IDs of open categories.

Here is example with a separate variable to store IDs of open categories:

```
const menu = [
  {
    label: "Category 1",
    key: "category_1",
    subcategories: [
      {
        label: "1 - Subcategory 1",
        key: "1_subcategory_1",
      },
      {
        label: "1 - Subcategory 2",
        key: "1_subcategory_2",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: "Category 2",
    key: "category_2",
    subcategories: [
      {
        label: "2 - Subcategory 1",
        key: "2_subcategory_1",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const openCategories = ref([]);

const toggleSubcategories = (categoryId) => {
  if(openCategories.value.includes(categoryId)) {            
    openCategories.value.splice(openCategories.value.indexOf(categoryId), 1);
  } else {
    openCategories.value.push(categoryId);
  }
}
```

```
<template>
  <div v-for="category in menu" :key="category.key">
    <div @click="toggleSubcategories(category.key)">
      <span> {{ category.label }}</span>
    </div>
    <div v-if="openCategories.includes(category.key)">
      <div
        v-for="subcategory in category.subcategories"
        :key="subcategory.key"
      >
        {{ subcategory.label }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. The only problem is that your solution did not allow to remove the subcategories by reclicking on the category. So i do `const showSubcategories = (categoryId) => {
  if(openCategories.value.length === 0) {
    openCategories.value.push(categoryId);
  } else if(openCategories.value.includes(categoryId)) {
    openCategories.value = [];
  } else {
    openCategories.value = [];
    openCategories.value.push(categoryId);
  }` It works as it should but if you have an improvement to propose do not hesitate. Thanks again for clearing up my situation.

Comment: Yes, you can simplify this `if` statement a little. I updated the above code.